# Disable a cell(a column in the row) in the apex interactive grid

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

How to disable a cell in the apex interactive grid. I want to disable the column in a particular row based on a condition. The following code working for the item/fields, but I have to disable a cell.

$("#C").attr('readonly','readonly');
$("#C").addClass('apex_disabled');

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following [link](https://srihariravva.blogspot.com/2020/07/interactive-grid-conditional.html). There are couple of ways to achieve this.

Also for more information check the this [link](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4337530/apex-20-1-issue-with-disable-enable-of-ig-columns).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check and let you know.